# Multiple distinct keys from several documents in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have several documents like this:

```
{
  category:"rootCategory1";
  subCategory: "subCategory1";
  text: "some text";
}
{
  category:"rootCategory1";
  subCategory: "subCategory2";
  text: "some text";
}
{
  category:"rootCategory2";
  subCategory: "subCategory3";
  text: "some text";
}
{
  category:"rootCategory2";
  subCategory: "subCategory4";
  text: "some text";
}
```

Is it possible for me to get a document out like this:

```
{
  category:"rootCategory1";
  subCategories:[
      {
        title:"subCategory1";
        title:"subCategory2";
      }
  ]
}
{
  category:"rootCategory2";
  subCategories:[
      {
        title:"subCategory3";
        title:"subCategory4";
      }
  ]
}
```

through some kind of command?

I've tried looking at mapReduce but as far as I see it doesn't support multiple values.
I used it to make a concatenated string for the subCategories but I'd really like to put the load on the database, not the webapp I'm developing.

Thanks.

** Update:

I have added some titles under each subCategory, the first answer gave me alot of help but now, after a lot of trying and failing, the first answer gave me this:

```
{
 category:"someRootCategory",
 subCategory:[
       subCategory: "someSubCategory",
       subCategory: "someOtherSubCategory"
 ]
 title: "someTitle"
}
```

My documents are now like this:

```
{
 category:"rootCategory",
 subCategory:"subCategory",
 title:"title"
}
```

This makes me unable to identify which title belongs to which subcategory. How do I go about something like this: (Is it even possible?)

```
{
 category:"rootCategory",
 information:[
   {
   subCategory: "sub1",
   titles:[{
     title:"title1",
     title:"title2"
   }],
   subCategory:"sub2",
   titles:[{
     title:"title3"
   }]
 ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through a lot of trial and err I came to the conclusion of splitting up everything.

Like this:

rootCategories.json:

```
{
 "rootCategory": "someRootCategory"
}
```

subCategories.json:

```
{
 "subCategory": "someSubCategory",
 "relation": <a rootCategory's ObjectId>
}
```

articles.json:

```
{
 "title": "Some articletitle",
 "text": "Some articletext",
 "relation": <a subCategory's ObjectId>
}
```

This way I was able to sort titles/texts to what subcategory and rootcategory they belong to.

Don't know if this is the right way but this seems like the best way to solve our problem.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
db.yourcollection.aggregate(
{ $group: {
   _id:"$category",
   subCategories: {$addToSet: "$subCategory"}
  }
}
```

Check [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet) operator.